# parent.appendChild is not a function

Tags: angular

I want to use the renderer2's append child [function](https://angular.io/api/core/Renderer2#appendchild) but I'm having some difficulties moving whole components. Here's a shortened versions of my component.

ts:

```
@ViewChild('test', { static: false }) test;
@ViewChild('test2', { static: false }) test2;

this.renderer.appendChild(this.test, this.test2);
```

html:

```
<div #test></div>

<my-component #test2></my-component>
```

So essentially I just want to move `</my-component>` into the div above it using the `appendChild` function. But when I execute it, I get the error:

`parent.appendChild is not a function`

Any ideas why it's erroring?

Answer (score 13):

You should pass DOM elements to this method:

```
@ViewChild('test', { static: false }) test: ElementRef;
@ViewChild('test2', { static: false, read: ElementRef }) test2: ElementRef;
...

this.renderer.appendChild(this.test.nativeElement, this.test2.nativeElement);
```